# AudioContext.currentTime perpetually stuck at 0.010666666 on Chromebook

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, web-audio-api

On my Chromebook (Toshiba Chromebook 2 with Firmware Swanky_5216.238.5 and Chrome Version 46) I am trying to utilize the Web Audio API's clock via [AudioContext.currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/currentTime):

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
audioContext = new AudioContext();
console.log(audioContext.currentTime);
```

For some reason, only on the Chromebook does it not advance at all and remains forever at 0.010666666(...). I tested the same for Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m on Windows 10 and even Chrome for Android 6.0 and the clock works fine on both. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.  We had this bug, but it was fixed; not sure if it's reoccurred, or if it just didn't make it into 46.

Comment: I got this problem on Chrome 61.0.3163.71 on Windows 10; had to restart my computer.